# Appium : not able to set saved capability sets

Tags: appium, ui-automation, appium-ios

I am trying to do automation testing using Appium desktop for my iOS app. I have generated an ipa of my application.

Appium Desktop software contains 2 sections for every app. You have to defined some key value pairs in desired capabilities section like platformName, platformVersion etc...

I have set these key value pairs in desired capabilities section. But I want to saved some key value pairs which are common in "Saved Capability Sets". But I am not able to do that because this section is disable. I don't know how to enable it.

Any help is most welcome!!!

[image]

Comment: You can have a look on this https://automationlab0000.wordpress.com/2018/12/31/appium-desktop-for-locating-elements/   to solve ur issue

Answer (score 1):

After entering all the values click on Save As button which is in bottom right corner just beside start session button.

Give a name while saving. After saving you can find that in saved capability. It will get enabled after saving at least once.

Comment: This does not works all the time!